# How can I make this window & application time- track script produce sorted output?

Tags: scripts, python, productivity

There is an application usage time tracker script, that **Jacob Vlijm** wrote in another question. https://askubuntu.com/a/780542/654800

Due to small reputation I cannot comment there. So I will ask here, is it possible to sort entries by percentage of use, instead of current relative order?

Here is a script in case you don't want to check the original question.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

# -- set update/round time (seconds)
period = 5
# -- 
# don change anything below
home = os.environ["HOME"]
logdir = home+"/.usagelogs"

def currtime(tformat=None):
    return time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") if tformat == "file"\
           else time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

try:
    os.mkdir(logdir)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

# path to your logfile
log = logdir+"/"+currtime("file")+".txt"; startt = currtime()

def get(command):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def time_format(s):
    # convert time format from seconds to h:m:s
    m, s = divmod(s, 60); h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)

def summarize():
    with open(log, "wt" ) as report:
        totaltime = sum([it[2] for it in winlist])
        report.write("")
        for app in applist:
            wins = [r for r in winlist if r[0] == app]
            apptime = sum([it[2] for it in winlist if it[0] == app])
            appperc = round(100*apptime/totaltime)
            report.write(("-"*60)+"\n"+app+"\n"+time_format(apptime)+\
                         " ("+str(appperc)+"%)\n"+("-"*60)+"\n")
            for w in wins:
                wperc = str(round(100*w[2]/totaltime))
                report.write("   "+time_format(w[2])+" ("+\
                             wperc+"%)"+(6-len(wperc))*" "+w[1]+"\n")
        report.write("\n"+"="*60+"\nstarted: "+startt+"\t"+\
                     "updated: "+currtime()+"\n"+"="*60)

t = 0; applist = []; winlist = []
while True:
    time.sleep(period)
    frpid = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowpid"])
    frname = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowname"])
    app = get(["ps", "-p", frpid, "-o", "comm="]) if frpid != None else "Unknown"
    # fix a few names
    if "gnome-terminal" in app:
        app = "gnome-terminal"
    elif app == "soffice.bin":
        app = "libreoffice"
    # add app to list
    if not app in applist:
        applist.append(app)
    checklist = [item[1] for item in winlist]
    if not frname in checklist:
        winlist.append([app, frname, 1*period])
    else:
        winlist[checklist.index(frname)][
            2] = winlist[checklist.index(frname)][2]+1*period
    if t == 60/period:
        summarize()
        t = 0
    else:
        t += 1
```

Comment: Hi oiceod0 absoluitly, will post back today. Have to refresh my memory a bit :)

Comment: Hi oiceod0, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Same script, but producing *sorted* reports, either ascending or descending

I edited the script to produce sorted reports, either ascending or descending, to be set in the head of the script.

The sorting is done on both the order of the *applications*, as well as their *windows* (in the sublists per application).

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os
from operator import itemgetter

# -- set update/round time (seconds)
period = 5 
# -- set sorting order. up = most used first, use either "up" or "down"
order = "up"

# don change anything below
home = os.environ["HOME"]
logdir = home+"/.usagelogs"

def currtime(tformat=None):
    return time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") if tformat == "file"\
           else time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

try:
    os.mkdir(logdir)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

# path to your logfile
log = logdir+"/"+currtime("file")+".txt"; startt = currtime()

def get(command):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def time_format(s):
    # convert time format from seconds to h:m:s
    m, s = divmod(s, 60); h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)

def summarize():
    with open(log, "wt" ) as report:
        totaltime = sum([it[2] for it in winlist]) # total time
        report.write("")
        alldata = []      
        for app in applist:
            appdata = []; windata = []
            apptime = sum([it[2] for it in winlist if it[0] == app])
            appperc = round(100*apptime/totaltime)            
            for d in [app, apptime, appperc]:
                appdata.append(d)
            wins = [r for r in winlist if r[0] == app]            
            for w in wins:
                wperc = str(round(100*w[2]/totaltime))
                windata.append([w[1], w[2], wperc])                
            windata = sorted(windata, key=itemgetter(1))
            windata = windata[::-1] if order == "up" else windata
            appdata.append(windata); alldata.append(appdata)            
        alldata = sorted(alldata, key = itemgetter(1))
        alldata = alldata[::-1] if order == "up" else alldata        
        for item in alldata:
            app = item[0]; apptime = item[1]; appperc = item[2]
            report.write(
                ("-"*60)+"\n"+app+"\n"+time_format(apptime)\
                +" ("+str(appperc)+"%)\n"+("-"*60)+"\n"
                )            
            for w in item[3]:
                wname = w[0]; time = w[1]; perc = w[2]
                report.write(
                    "   "+time_format(time)+" ("+perc+"%)"\
                    +(6-len(perc))*" "+wname+"\n"
                    )
        report.write(
            "\n"+"="*60+"\nstarted: "+startt+"\t"+"updated: "\
            +currtime()+"\n"+"="*60
            )

t = 0; applist = []; winlist = []

while True:
    time.sleep(period)
    frpid = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowpid"])
    frname = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowname"])
    app = get([
        "ps", "-p", frpid, "-o", "comm="
        ]) if frpid != None else "Unknown"
    # fix a few names
    if "gnome-terminal" in app:
        app = "gnome-terminal"
    elif app == "soffice.bin":
        app = "libreoffice"
    # add app to list
    if not app in applist:
        applist.append(app)
    checklist = [item[1] for item in winlist]
    if not frname in checklist:
        winlist.append([app, frname, 1*period])
    else:
        winlist[checklist.index(frname)][
            2] = winlist[checklist.index(frname)][2]+1*period
    if t == 60/period:
        summarize()
        t = 0
    else:
        t += 1
```

It produces output like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
firefox
0:08:25 (97%)
------------------------------------------------------------
   0:06:50 (79%)    Sort by percentage of use in a python script - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
   0:01:30 (17%)    scripts - Is there software which time- tracks window & application usage? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
   0:00:05 (1%)     Ask Ubuntu General Room | chat.stackexchange.com - Mozilla Firefox
------------------------------------------------------------
gedit
0:00:10 (2%)
------------------------------------------------------------
   0:00:10 (2%)     2017_02_15_20_47_10.txt (~/.usagelogs) - gedit
------------------------------------------------------------
zenity
0:00:05 (1%)
------------------------------------------------------------
   0:00:05 (1%)     Paste snippets

============================================================
started: 2017-02-15 20:58:19    updated: 2017-02-15 21:07:03
============================================================
```

#### To use

1. The script needs `xdotool` to get the window's information

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `window_logs.py`
3. Test- run the script: tart the script by the command (from a terminal):

   ```
   python3 /path/to/window_logs.py
   ```

   After one minute, the script creates a log file with the first results in `~/.usagelogs`. The file is time- stamped with the creation date & time. The file is updated once per minute.

   At the bottom of the file, you can see both the start- time and the time-stamp of the latest edit. This way you can always see what is the file's time span.

   If the script restarts, a new file with a new (start-) time stamp is created.
4. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/window_logs.py"
   ```

#### Reverse sorting order

To reverse the sorting order, simply change the argument in the head of the script:

```py
# -- set sorting order. up = most used first, use either "up" or "down"
order = "up"
```

---

**NB** Please read the **Notes** and **More notes** sections in the [linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/780542/72216)!

---