# How to get notified when a specific process started/ended?

Tags: kernel, python

My user wants a report about his usage on Ubuntu for specific processes. Like the elapsed time, CPU , RAM consumption ... etc 
I built a real time monitoring tool depends on log files generated every day. But it seems to be not accurate in some cases also the generated log file have more than *70,000* record every day.

sample of records generated :

```
....
chrome::09-58-40
plasmashell::10-01-28
konsole::10-11-32
dolphin::10-12-24
....
```

So is there any way to force the kernel to write a record with accounting information to the accounting file whenever a process starts/ends ?

Comment: Kind of what this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883557/how-can-i-make-this-window-application-time-track-script-produce-sorted-outpu and this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/779873/is-there-software-which-time-tracks-window-application-usage/780542#780542 is?

Comment: @JacobVlijm
Thanks this is what I am looking for

Comment: Ah, thanks for mentioning. Will mark it as duplicate.